# How do I return a value from a function into a variable in javascript then display it using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to JS and I have been struggling with this for a few hours now.

```html
<script>
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function myFunction()
{
  var Ra = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var Rb = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  var Ea = (1) / ( (1) + (Math.pow((10), ((Rb - Ra) / (400)))) );
  var Eap = Ea * 100;
  return Eap;
}
var result = myFunction();
</script>

<div class="result"> 
Your probability of winning is: <script> document.write(result); </script>
</div>
```

Basically, I have taken two values from the user, sent it to the function for some calculations. I want to use the value of the variable 'Eap' to display the result of the calculations one way or another. I cannot use the variable directly for I assume its scope is within the function only? And I cannot store the return value of the whole function.
[image]

Comment: `document.querySelector('.result').innerText = result`. You need to execute it every time the button is clicked, if you put it out of the function it will be executed only once at the startup. Pay attention because `document.write` may not do what you think it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.textContent`.

As it's 2022 I changed `.getElementById` to `.querySelector` and `var` to `const`.

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const Ra = document.querySelector('#input1').value;
  const Rb = document.querySelector('#input2').value;
  const Ea = (1) / ((1) + (Math.pow((10), ((Rb - Ra) / (400)))));
  const Eap = Ea * 100;
  document.querySelector('#result').textContent = Eap;
})
```

```html
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">

<button id="button">update</button>

<p>result: <span id="result"></span></p>
```